Ubuntu Server sometimes only partially boots
I installed latest Ubuntu Server on my old gaming PC to use it for hosting some stuff. I installed and configured wireguard, samba, cockpit, but I have a strange problem. What happens is that sometimes, usually on first boot of the system in a day, the server only loads like half the stuff. I can't use SSH, wireguard, samba, cockpit because its services simply don't get loaded.
Even short press power button which usually shuts off server doesn't work. I can still ping server just fine though.
I must forcefully shut down the server by long press of the power button. And then on the next start of the system immediately after everything usually just boots correctly.
Of course I tried troubleshooting and got journalctl logs of bad and good boots.
The thing is that I don't see any obvious errors in the logs, it just appears that when it doesn't boot correctly, it doesn't load up all services it should.
I suspect that it might be in emergency mode or something, but I can't find a reason for it going into it.
I read that people had their systems going into emergency mode because of filesystem errors or misconfigured fstab, but I don't see any of that in my logs.
Also if that was the case I suspect it would never boot correctly, but it does.
Can someone take a look at these logs?
I'm not embedding them here since they are quite large.
This bad boot was immediately before the good boot.
bad https://pastebin.com/CqwV2rUg
good https://pastebin.com/7ynUvfvq
I don't know what to do anymore, to try reinstalling or maybe another distro?
